# WordPress setting with select - where is my mistake?

Tags: plugin-development, options, settings-api, select, plugin-options

I have two option callbacks in my plugin, one with a ckeckbox and one with a select field. The first one is working perfectly, the second not. The select field doesn't save its value. I double checked the code which registers the two settings, I assume my mistake is somewhere in the callback.

Any ideas?

Checkbox (works):

```
public function myplugin_post_menu_cb() {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $this->option_name . '_post_menu' . '" value="1" "' . checked(1, get_option('myplugin_post_menu'), false) . '" />';
}
```

Select (doesn't work):

```
public function myplugin_admin_bar_cb() {
    echo '<select name="' . $this->option_name . '_admin_bar' . '">';
        echo '<option value="1" "' . selected( get_option('myplugin_admin_bar'), 1 ) . '">1</option>';
        echo '<option value="2" "' . selected( get_option('myplugin_admin_bar'), 2 ) . '">2</option>';
    echo '</select>';
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that in your calls to `selected()` you haven't set the 3rd parameter to `false`. For both `selected()` and `checked()` if you don't do this it will echo the attribute immediately, which won't work properly if you're using it inside a concatenated string.

So change:

```
selected( get_option('myplugin_admin_bar'), 1 )
```

To:

```
selected( get_option('myplugin_admin_bar'), 1, false )
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved! Here is the full code, if anyone is interested:

```
public function myplugin_admin_bar_cb() {
    echo '<select name="' . $this->option_name . '_admin_bar' . '">';
        echo '<option value="1" ' . selected(1, get_option('myplugin_admin_bar'), false ) . '>On</option>';
        echo '<option value="2" ' . selected(2, get_option('myplugin_admin_bar'), false ) . '>Off</option>';
    echo '</select>';       
}
```